# Want to check if an object exists on an array

Tags: arrays, swift, object

For example, my array looks something like this

**data.json**

```
Questions("Question":"KEK1" , "Answers": ["", "", "", ""], "Answer": 1)
Questions("Question":"KEK2" , "Answers": ["", "", "", ""], "Answer": 1)
Questions("Question":"KEK3" , "Answers": ["", "", "", ""], "Answer": 1)
Questions("Question":"BAB1" , "Answers": ["", "", "", ""], "Answer": 1)
Questions("Question":"BAB2" , "Answers": ["", "", "", ""], "Answer": 1)
Questions("Question":"BAB3" , "Answers": ["", "", "", ""], "Answer": 1)
```

**mycode:**

This is the code that i use red the data from data.json and put them in an array called Questions

```
struct Question {
    var Question: String!
    var Answers: [String]!
    var Answer: Int!

    init(item: [String: Any])
    {
        self.Question = item["Question"] as? String
        self.Answers = item["Answers"] as? [String]
        self.Answer = item["Answer"] as? Int
    }
}

class LittleTestViewController: UIViewController {

var Questions = [Question]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  jsonParsingQuestionsFile()
}

//parsing fata from json file
    func jsonParsingQuestionsFile ()
    {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json"),
            let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe), options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as? [[String : Any]] else{
                return
        }
        for item in array
        {
            self.Questions.append(Question(item: item))
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see if some objects exist on the array and then do something.
For example:

```
var Questions = [Question]()
var kek = "KEK"
var bab = "BAB"

if kek exists on Questions
{
// do something
}else if bab exists on Questions
{
// do something
}else
{
// end
}
```

I guess it's something like `Questions.contains...`

Comment: What is `myArray`? It is clearly not an array. What are these labels Question, Answers, Answer? Is this some custom object type? If so, show it. Also, please use small letters for variable names and capital letters for type names.

Comment: It’s a json file.. I parse that data from json file to myArray

Comment: Then show that json. right now I have no clue what `myArray` is supposed to look like. What you currently show certainly is not an array.

Comment: You still have not done what I asked you to do. You can call this thing an array but it is not an array. Show the parsing and show the declaration of `myArray`'s type.

Comment: edited check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `filter`. To illustrate, I'll simplify considerably. Assume this struct:

```
struct Question {
    let q: String
}
```

Then assume this array:

```
let questions = [Question(q:"KEK1"), Question(q:"KEK2"), 
    Question(q:"KEK3"), Question(q:"KEK4"), Question(q:"KEK5"), 
    Question(q:"KEK6"), Question(q:"KEK7"), Question(q:"KEK8"), 
    Question(q:"KEK9"), Question(q:"KEK10"), Question(q:"KEK11"), 
    Question(q:"BAB1"), Question(q:"BAB2"), Question(q:"BAB3"), 
    Question(q:"BAB4"), Question(q:"BAB5"), Question(q:"BAB6"), 
    Question(q:"BAB7"), Question(q:"BAB8"), Question(q:"BAB9"), 
    Question(q:"BAB10"), Question(q:"BAB11")]
```

Now let's say the problem is: from that array, get only the KEK questions. We can do that with `filter`:

```
let questionsWithKek = questions.filter{$0.q.contains("KEK")}
// result is: [Question(q: "KEK1"), Question(q: "KEK2"), Question(q: "KEK3"), 
//    Question(q: "KEK4"), Question(q: "KEK5"), Question(q: "KEK6"), 
//    Question(q: "KEK7"), Question(q: "KEK8"), Question(q: "KEK9"), 
//    Question(q: "KEK10"), Question(q: "KEK11")]
```

It is then trivial to cycle thru `questionsWithKek` and do something with each one.

If the question really is whether the original `questions` array contains *any* KEK questions, then just look to see whether `questionsWithKek` is empty.

Comment: it works and it filters, but i have KEK1,KEK2,.....,KEK9,KEK10 and it only goes to KEK1 KEK2 KEK4 ΚEK4 ΚΕΚ5 ΚΕΚ6 ΚΕΚ7 and ΚΕΚ8 . It doesn't find 9 and 10.

Comment: I did the same for the `bab` but it doesnt find all bab it only goes to `bab1`.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, because you still did not provide a coherent test input and desired output. I assure you that my answer works exactly as I describe.